# Use calendar module function

Tags: python, calendar

I need to use one of the calendar module functions, but python renders weird output.

```
from calendar import Calendar as cal
def calend(year):
    print cal.yeardatescalendar(year, width=3)
cal(2015)
>>> TypeError: unbound method yeardatescalendar() must be called with Calendar instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Ok, lets try

```
from calendar import Calendar as cal
def calend(year):
    y = cal(2015)
    print cal.yeardatescalendar(y, width=3)
cal(2015)
>>> TypeError: yeardatescalendar() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

What am i doing wrong?
P.S. Documentation for the module seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Both chunks of code run fine for me in Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yeardatescalendar` is an instance method of the `Calendar` class, so to call it you need to first create an instance of `Calendar` class, then call the method on the instance, like this:

```
import Calendar
def calend(year):                       
    mycalendar = calendar.Calendar()
    print mycalendar.yeardatescalendar(year, width=3)
```

If you call the method on the class without first creating an instance then you get the `UnboundLocalError` like in your first example.

`Calendar.yeardatescalendar` takes an integer as it's first parameter - in your second example you passed it a Calendar instance.